# cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi warning

Tags: cpanel

My operating system of vps server: Centos 6 (64-bit version)

Have root access

I have installed cpannel there

My server ip: 142.44.241.235

Cpannel is installed: proof: http://142.44.241.235:2083

But I see unexpected error when I go to: http://142.44.241.235

It is redirecting me http://142.44.241.235/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel completely manages your web server, email, and database. Since you haven't configured a webpage inside of cpanel, it's sending you to the default blue and yellow webpage that tells you that there is no website configured yet: "If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider:"

Comment: If you used to have a website there, you'll have to add it inside of cpanel.

Comment: I can enter into the cpannel, can upload files, database create etc using IP/cpanel. But I can not see the live site using ip

Comment: May be require to edit some config files of cpanel entering root access of vps

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I forget where you set it up, but the option is in WHM under IP Addresses somewhere.

Comment: So use WHM not CPanel to set that option

Comment: yes I am using WHM: http://142.44.241.235:2087

Comment: It is working well but my main ip is not showing contents from browser